# Models of infinite cardinal and compactness

Tags: logic, model-theory, compactness

I'm stuck with this problem:

> $L$ is first-order language with identity and $L_q$ a language obtained by adding to $L$ the quantifier $Q$. If $P$ is a formula and $x$ a variable, $QxP$ is a formula of $L_q$. If $A$ is a $L_q$-structure, then $A\vDash QxP$ if and only if $\#\left(\{a \in |A| : A\vDash P[a]\}\right)>\aleph_0$.

I have to show that there exists $T\subset\operatorname{For}(L_q)$ of cardinal superior to $\aleph_0$ such that T does not have a model and every finite subset has a model

Any ideas??

thanks!

Comment: And the quantifier $Q$ is...?

Comment: Use negation and Q to say the universe is countable.  Then for uncountably many constant symbols, say they're all distinct.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: you should post this as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

To get this off the unanswered list:

> Use negation and Q to say the universe is countable. Then for uncountably many constant symbols, say they're all distinct. – [Andreas Blass](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/48510/andreas-blass) [Jan 22 at 19:52](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284455/models-of-infinite-cardinal-and-compactness#comment620737_284455)